# Is my graph and tree proofing correct for this degree sequence?

Tags: graph-theory, trees

I was wondering if you could help verify if my answer is correct. The question is:

> Is (1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 1, 3, 3, 4, 5) a degree sequence of a graph?
>
> Is it a degree sequence of a tree?

**My answers are:**

Yes it is a graph because the sum of the degrees / 2 is 12 and even, therefore making it a graph.

No, it is not a tree because the tree satisfies $|V| = |E| - 1$ and $12 - 1 = 11$. There are 13 vertices in total. Are these right?

Answer (score 2):

**UPDATED**

(2) is not correct, this potentially could be a tree. For the sequence to be a tree you need $|V| = |E| + 1$, not as you wrote. But you have the sum of all degrees is $S=24$, so $|E| = S/2 = 12$ and $|V| = 13$. Can you construct the actual tree?

For (1) you did not prove it is a graph. Can you construct a graph with such a sequence? Showing one would be a proof...

Comment: (2) is wrong. V=E+1.

Comment: @SueVanHattum changed the answer to state that explicitly

Comment: @gt6989b It looks like here we have $|E|=12$ (don't forget that the sum of degrees is $2|E|$) which matches what we'd expect for a $13$-vertex tree. (It's also worth noting that even though in general, the existence of a graph takes some checking, in the cases of trees checking that the hypothetical number of edges is right suffices: see for example [this post](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2938257).)

Comment: 12+1=13. And this can be the degree sequence of a tree. The OP would have to show what tree it works with.

Comment: @MishaLavrov made the changes.